# MassTransit - Cannot override the Consume method from RoutingSlipResponseProxy

Tags: c#, masstransit

I'm trying to set up a `RoutingSlipResponseProxy` that will prevent a response from being sent if there is no `RequestId`. I am trying to do this by overriding the `Consume` method in my `RoutingSlipResponseProxy`, like so:

```
public class MigrateResponseProxy : RoutingSlipResponseProxy<IMigrationRequested, IMigrationComplete>
{
    public new async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<RoutingSlipCompleted> context)
    {
        var isRequest = context.Message.Variables.ContainsKey("RequestId");
        if (!isRequest)
            return;

        var request = context.Message.GetVariable<IMigrationRequested>("Request");
        var requestId = context.Message.GetVariable<Guid>("RequestId");

        Uri responseAddress = null;
        if (context.Message.Variables.ContainsKey("ResponseAddress"))
            responseAddress = context.Message.GetVariable<Uri>("ResponseAddress");

        if (responseAddress == null)
            throw new ArgumentException($"The response address could not be found for the faulted routing slip: {context.Message.TrackingNumber}");

        var endpoint = await context.GetResponseEndpoint<IMigrationComplete>(responseAddress, requestId).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var response = await CreateResponseMessage(context, request);

        await endpoint.Send(response).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    ... remaining code ...
}
```

This is basically the same code as the [original method](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/5e2a416384f005c392ead139f5c4af34511c56db/src/MassTransit/Courier/RoutingSlipResponseProxy.cs#L19), except with a check for the RequestId at the beginning. However, when debugging through the code, it seems as though this overridden method is never getting called, and instead the parent method is getting called. Is there something I might be missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods aren't virtual, so you won't be able to override them. In this case, you'd be better of copying the proxy code into your own project instead of using the implementation that's included with MassTransit.

> You're welcome to submit a PR to make those methods virtual.